# GHC: failure to infer phantom type parameter

Tags: haskell, tuples, ghc, phantom-types

So I'm trying to make a type for variable-length tuples, basically as a prettier version of `Either a (Either (a,b) (Either (a,b,c) ...))` and `Either (Either (Either ... (x,y,z)) (y,z)) z`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}
module Temp where

-- type level addition
data Unit
data Succ n

class Summable n m where
  type Sum n m :: *

instance Summable Unit m where
  type Sum Unit m = Succ m

instance Summable n m => Summable (Succ n) m where
  type Sum (Succ n) m = Succ (Sum n m)

-- variable length tuple, left-to-right
data a :+ b = a :+ Maybe b
infixr 5 :+

class Prependable t r s where
  type Prepend t r s :: *
  prepend :: r -> Maybe s -> Prepend t r s

instance Prependable Unit x y where
  type Prepend Unit x y = x :+ y
  prepend = (:+)

instance Prependable n x y => Prependable (Succ n) (w :+ x) y where
  type Prepend (Succ n) (w :+ x) y = w :+ Prepend n x y
  prepend (w :+ Nothing) _ = w :+ Nothing
  prepend (w :+ Just x) y = w :+ Just (prepend x y)

-- variable length tuple, right-to-left
data a :- b = Maybe a :- b
infixl 5 :-

class Appendable t r s where
  type Append t r s :: *
  append :: Maybe r -> s -> Append t r s

instance Appendable Unit x y where
  type Append Unit x y = x :- y
  append = (:-)

instance Appendable n x y => Appendable (Succ n) x (y :- z) where
  type Append (Succ n) x (y :- z) = Append n x y :- z
  append _ (Nothing :- z) = Nothing :- z
  append x (Just y :- z) = Just (append x y) :- z
```

However, the compiler seems unable to infer the phantom type parameter of `prepend` or `append` in the recursive cases:

```
Temp.hs:32:40:
    Could not deduce (Prepend t1 x y ~ Prepend n x y)
    from the context (Prependable n x y)
      bound by the instance declaration at Temp.hs:29:10-61
    NB: `Prepend' is a type function, and may not be injective
    In the return type of a call of `prepend'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `(prepend x y)'
    In the second argument of `(:+)', namely `Just (prepend x y)'

Temp.hs:49:34:
    Could not deduce (Append t0 x y ~ Append n x y)
    from the context (Appendable n x y)
      bound by the instance declaration at Temp.hs:46:10-59
    NB: `Append' is a type function, and may not be injective
    In the return type of a call of `append'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `(append x y)'
    In the first argument of `(:-)', namely `Just (append x y)'
```

Is there anything I can do to help the compiler make this inference?

Answer (score 7):

The important part of the error message here is the:

```
NB: `Prepend' is a type function, and may not be injective
```

What does this mean? It means that there might be multiple `instance Prependable` such that their `type Prepend ... = a`, so that if you infer some `Prepend` to be `a`, you don't necessarily know which instance it belongs to.

You can solve this by using [data types in type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families), which have the advantage that you don't deal with type functions, which are surjective but *might* be injective, and instead with type "relations", which are bijective (So every `Prepend` type can only belong to one type family, and every type family has a distinct `Prepend` type).

(If you want me to show a solution with data types in type families, leave a comment! Basically, just use a `data Prepend` instead of `type Prepend`)

Comment: Ah, thanks for teasing out the meaning of that error message for me.

Comment: Note that the original code *does* use type families (specifically, type synonym families); what it should use instead is data families.

Comment: @ehird, I always thought that "type aliases in type classes" still didn't belong to the type families extension, but TIL.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with was to add a dummy argument to tie `prepend` and `append` to the phantom parameter:

```
-- as above, except...

unsucc :: Succ n -> n
unsucc _ = undefined

class Prependable t r s where
  type Prepend t r s :: *
  prepend :: t -> r -> Maybe s -> Prepend t r s

instance Prependable Unit x y where
  type Prepend Unit x y = x :+ y
  prepend _ = (:+)

instance Prependable n x y => Prependable (Succ n) (w :+ x) y where
  type Prepend (Succ n) (w :+ x) y = w :+ Prepend n x y
  prepend _ (w :+ Nothing) _ = w :+ Nothing
  prepend t (w :+ Just x) y = w :+ Just (prepend (unsucc t) x y)

class Appendable t r s where
  type Append t r s :: *
  append :: t -> Maybe r -> s -> Append t r s

instance Appendable Unit x y where
  type Append Unit x y = x :- y
  append _ = (:-)

instance Appendable n x y => Appendable (Succ n) x (y :- z) where
  type Append (Succ n) x (y :- z) = Append n x y :- z
  append _ _ (Nothing :- z) = Nothing :- z
  append t x (Just y :- z) = Just (append (unsucc t) x y) :- z
```